# cocos2d maintain a ccmenuitem list

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, menuitem

I'm loading a list of items

```
NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
    Items *items = [ItemParser loadItemsForALevel:selectedLevel fromASuperLevel:selectedSuperLevel];
```

In my for loop I'm adding to an NSMutableArray in order to display it to my menu layer

```
for (Item *item in items.items) {

//Initialing a CCMenuItem and calling a removeMethod
CMenuItem *anItem = [[CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:item.picture]
 selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:item.picture]
target:self
selector:@selector(removeMethod:)] retain];

NSString *textToDisplay;
textToDisplay = item.ItemText;
[listOfItems addObject:textToDisplay];

}

-(void)removeMethod:(id)sender {
CCMenuItemSprite *pointedItem = (CCMenuItemSprite *)sender;

//Now I'm removing only from the layer
[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:pointedItem selector:@selector(removeFromParentAndCleanup:)]

//How do I remove it from array?

}
```

How do I remove the selected item from the listOfItems array and update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 'textToDisplay' as global variable.. In removeMethod. You can remove it from an array using

[listOfItems removeObjectAtIndex:[listOfItems indexOfObject:textToDisplay]];

Hope this one helps :-)

Comment: Thanks! It crashes and returns: `Program received signal:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, any doubt? ;)

Comment: Just check that the textToDisplay is returning a string.